# 404 document you requested not found

Tags: air, http-status-code-404

I have a file on my web server (.air) extension that I know exists because it is there when I access the file from FileZilla. However, when I try to access it on the web, I get the above error. If I change the extension of the file to (.zip), it works and the file is downloaded. But I don't want to change the extension.

Any idea? Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to specify the .air url as a link in the web page. `<a href="file.air">Download</a>`

Comment: An update in case someone has this issue: It turns out the web server where the file is hosted must have the MIME type of the file, in this case, the .air file MIME type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone has this issue, here is what fixed it for me:

I added the MIME type for .air on my hosting service. Depending on your host, you might need to go to virtual directories, and add the MIME type for the file you want to download.